# Stripping 3 parentheses in regex

Tags: regex

I run a small forum that has an issue with people using parentheses to bracket statements. They do it to signify they are talking about Jews. I guess it is called echoes or something. So they will put a name like (((Prominent Person))) like that in the middle of a conversation.

I have recently been trying to combat this without just banning people that can't behave. I have a decent word filter but it doesn't block that. I recently installed something that allows me to use regex to strip things out but I am having trouble finding the proper string that doesn't break everything else.

"/\W{3}(.*)\W{3}/","$1"

The first is the matching string and the comma separates what is left. This string works, it strips the parentheses out and leaves everything else alone. The problem is that the string is too broad. It also strips out any [ brackets as well which breaks all of the bbcode in a post. Any post that has any number of at least 3 brackets will be broken after that.

I have been playing with different strings on regex101 but not finding the best solution. I need any time that ((( or ))) is seen to strip out those and replace it with nothing, like it never happened. It has to be exactly three and only ((( and not the other brackets it could trigger on.

Does anyone have a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\({3}(.*)\){3}`

https://regex101.com/r/wD5TMb/1

So in your format probably: `"/\({3}(.*)\){3}/","$1"`

Comment: This did exactly what I needed, I was so close!